# Save playing media state in rotate window Mono for Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, media, state

How can I save playing media state when the window rotating by user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may follow this link in order to stop refreshing the activity on orientation change:

[Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Comment: There are many answers to this question. If you are referring to `android:configChanges`, this goes against the philosophy of the framework, and I would not recommend this option. From the [Android dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config): *Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.*

Answer (score 2):

With `onSaveInstanteState`, like you always do for [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

This also means that you need to keep track of the MediaPlayerService state yourself, since [there is no way to get the state of the media player](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=800).